# "Масляный" - правильно ли это?

Tags: орфография

Натолкнулась в сети на спор вокруг спора "масляный". Предполагалось, что это неправильно, и надо говорить "масленный". Или это два разных слова?
Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ОБЩЕЕ ПРАВИЛО

ВЫБИРАЕМ СПОСОБ ОБРАЗОВАНИЯ: Существительное масло или  глагол маслить:

А)  масляная краска, масляное пятно – от существительного масло, то есть сделанное из масла или  содержащее масло, отымённый суффикс ЯН;

Б)  масленый  блин, масленая каша, масленые руки, Масленая неделя (Масленица) – от  глагола маслить, выбор одной буквы Н при отсутствии 4-х признаков, также в переносном значении:  масленые глазки, масленый (льстивый)  голос;   .

В) замасленная одежда, промасленная бумага – выбор двух  НН по  правилу 4-х признаков (наличие приставки).

РЕШЕНИЕ

Обычно можно встретить два варианта: масляный и масленый. Слово "масленный" возможно только при наличии зависимого слова: масленный с двух сторон.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это два разных слова: "масляный" - прилагательное, "масленный" - причастие.